# Cannot read property 'toDataURL' of undefined -- Save Canvas as images

Tags: javascript

Canvas2Image.js

```
return {

    saveAsPNG : function(oCanvas, bReturnImg, iWidth, iHeight) {
        if (!bHasDataURL) {
            return false;
        }
        var oScaledCanvas = scaleCanvas(oCanvas, iWidth, iHeight);
        var strData = oScaledCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        if (bReturnImg) {
            return makeImageObject(strData);
        } else {
            saveFile(strData.replace("image/png", strDownloadMime));
        }
        return true;
    },

    saveAsJPEG : function(oCanvas, bReturnImg, iWidth, iHeight) {
        if (!bHasDataURL) {
            return false;
        }

        var oScaledCanvas = scaleCanvas(oCanvas, iWidth, iHeight);
        var strMime = "image/jpeg";
        var strData = oScaledCanvas.toDataURL(strMime);

        // check if browser actually supports jpeg by looking for the mime type in the data uri.
        // if not, return false
        if (strData.indexOf(strMime) != 5) {
            return false;
        }

        if (bReturnImg) {
            return makeImageObject(strData);
        } else {
            saveFile(strData.replace(strMime, strDownloadMime));
        }
        return true;
    },
```

Call using this:

```
function exportAndSaveCanvas()  {

    // Get the canvas screenshot as PNG
    var screenshot = Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas, true);

    // This is a little trick to get the SRC attribute from the generated <img> screenshot
    canvas.parentNode.appendChild(screenshot);
    screenshot.id = "canvasimage";      
    data = $('#canvasimage').attr('src');
    canvas.parentNode.removeChild(screenshot);


    // Send the screenshot to PHP to save it on the server
    var url = 'upload/export.php';
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST", 
        url: url,
        dataType: 'text',
        data: {
            base64data : data
        }
    });
```

Wanting to covert the convert it to images and save but get this error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toDataURL' of undefined. Any idea how can i solve it?

** i copy these codes from other source and other people using seem to be working fine with these codes. Did i miss out something?

**** Both oScaledCanvas and oCanvas are undefined. Why?

Comment: Are you making sure `scaleCanvas()` returns a canvas element

Comment: Need more details, the error is most likely not in this code but in the code that actually calls these methods.

Comment: @lleaff I had uploaded the method in calling the jquery

Comment: oScaledCanvas is undefined, might be your scaleCanvas function does not return canvas..? share the relevant code...

Comment: @DemoUser do take a look

Comment: can you share the sources..? the scaleCanvas should be a function defined somewhere in the source itself you copied the code from..

Comment: @DemoUser i cant find any that define scaleCanvas as a function. Only var scaleCanvas = function(oCanvas, iWidth, iHeight) --> variable

Comment: I think is not scaleCanvas() problem as the var oCanvas above of the function is also undefined